# Creating a max method in ruby

Tags: ruby

Could I get a little help please.

Return the largest number from the array, without using max. Make the tests pass. Do not use max, for or while.

```
def max(items)
  # your code here
end

puts max([1,2,3,4,5,6]) == 6
puts max([4,5,6,1,2,3]) == 6
puts max([9,8,7,6,5,3,1]) == 9
```

This is the code I first attempted. I am pretty new and could be way off base. Also, I am sure it is incomplete. 
Not sure why I am getting so many downvotes on this question. Could someone explain that as well.

```
def max(items)
x = items.each
  if x > items
    items = x
    x
  end



end
```

Comment: Just edited my first incomplete attempt at it. May not even be on the right track at all looking at the answers I have got so far from people.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use `sort`?

```
def max(items)
  items.sort.last
end

p max([1,2,3,4,5,6]) # => 6
p max([4,5,6,1,2,3]) # => 6
p max([9,8,7,6,5,3,1]) # => 9
```

Comment: You know, I did not even think about that. Looks good to me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think this one is pretty clean and in the spirit of the exercise:

```
a = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1]
a.reduce { |a, b| a > b ? a : b }
#=> 9
```

Comment: `(a.first)` is redundant, `Enumerable#reduce` will use the first element as the initial memo if it is not provided explicitly: `a.reduce { |a, b| a > b ? a : b }`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Good point, thanks! I've been switching languages a bit too much lately, so occasionally it becomes a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is less efficient than the iterative proposals, but can nevertheless be fun:

```
def max(items)
  return nil if items.size < 1       # no data, no answer
  return items[0] if items.size < 2  # one element is trivially the max
  mid = items.size / 2               # otherwise, find the midpoint of the array
  first_half_max = max(items[0...mid])  # recursively find max of 1st half
  second_half_max = max(items[mid..-1]) # recursively find max of 2nd half
  first_half_max < second_half_max ? second_half_max : first_half_max  # pick the larger
end
```

I went with an approach that cuts the list into halves rather than the easier "compare the first element to the max of the rest".  This one keeps the recursion depth under control, and won't give stack overflows even for very large lists.

Answer (score 0):

Obeying the letter of the law but perhaps disobeying the spirit:

```
def max items
  items.max_by(&:itself)
end
```

or

```
def max items
  items.min_by { |i| -i }
end
```

or

```
def max items
  items.minmax.last
end
```

all give the following outputs:

```
puts max([1,2,3,4,5,6])   # 6
puts max([4,5,6,1,2,3])   # 6
puts max([9,8,7,6,5,3,1]) # 9
```

See [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by), [`Enumerable#min_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) and [`Enumerable#minmax`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax) for more details.

---

More within the spirit, we can do something like this:

```
def max items
  m = items[0]
  items[1..items.length-1].each { |n| m = n if n > m }
  m
end
```

This assumes the first element is the maximum, then goes through all the remaining elements from left-to-right and replaces the maximum `m` if it encounters a larger number `n`.

Comment: I don't think you should mutate your input like that (the last snippet)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yup. Lapse in judgement:(

Comment: Worry not! Here's a worthy replacement: `m, *items = items` (although slighly more wasteful, yes).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev will your suggestion not mutate the input as well?